# using leaky relu in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

How can I change `G_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z, G_W1) + G_b1)` to leaky relu? I have tried looping over the tensor using `max(value, 0,01*value)` but I get `TypeError: Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed.`

I also tried to find the source code on relu on Tensorflow github so that I can modify it to leaky relu but I couldn't find it..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could write one based on `tf.relu`, something like:

```
def lrelu(x, alpha):
  return tf.nn.relu(x) - alpha * tf.nn.relu(-x)
```

**EDIT**

Tensorflow 1.4 now has a native [`tf.nn.leaky_relu`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/leaky_relu).

Answer (score 24):

If alpha < 1 (it should be), you can use `tf.maximum(x, alpha * x)`

Comment: This confused me until I remembered that relu is really just max(x, 0)

Answer (score 7):

A leaky relu function has been included with [release 1.4.0-rc1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.4.0-rc0)
as `tf.nn.leaky_relu`.

Documentation page: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/leaky_relu .

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU
```