# Module object has no attribute leaky_relu

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to run the code from [here](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN) which is an implementatino of Generative Adversarial Networks using keras python. I followed the instructions and install all the requirements. Then i tried to run the code for [DCGAN](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/dcgan/dcgan.py). However, it seems that there is some issue with the compatibility of the libraries. I am receiving the following message when i am running the code:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'leaky_relu'

```
File "main.py", line 176, in <module>
dcgan = DCGAN()
File "main.py", line 25, in __init__
self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
File "main.py", line 84, in build_discriminator
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
File "/opt/libraries/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 492, in add
output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
File "/opt/libraries/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 617, in __call__
output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
File "/opt/libraries/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py", line 46, in call
return K.relu(inputs, alpha=self.alpha)
File "/opt/libraries/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2918, in relu
x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha)
```

I am using keras`Version: 2.1.3` while tensorflow`Version: 1.2.1`
 and Theano`Version: 1.0.1+40.g757b4d5`

Any idea why am I receiving that issue?

**EDIT:**

The error is located in the line 84 in the build_discriminator:

```
function:`model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))`
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback, we don't know what code raised that error or where

Comment: Indeed you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307072/using-leaky-relu-in-tensorflow/45307280#45307280), `leaky_relu` was added to tensorflow on version 1.4. So you might wanna check if your tensorflow installation is at least on version 1.4.

Comment: Not just might, but definitely should update it. I missed the part where you say your tensorflow installation is on version 1.2.1

Comment: I found out that I cant use CUDA in the 1.4 version of tensorflow. Is there any alternative around?

Comment: Try using Theano as backend.

Either change the `.keras/keras.json` file or set the environment variable `KERAS_BACKEND=theano`

Comment: Also, why wouldn't you be able to use CUDA when upgrading?
Tensorflow 1.2.1 uses CUDNN 5, while 1.4 uses CUDNN 6. So if you upgrade CUDNN you should be able to use CUDA

Comment: Yes true, just started and I am messed with all those new dependencies.