# Julia - How to use leaky relu?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, julia

How can I use the leaky relu function in Julia ?

The following command does not work:

```
nn.leaky_relu(features, alpha)
```

In python, there is [this function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/leaky_relu):

```
tf.nn.leaky_relu(
    features,
    alpha=0.2,
    name=None
)
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

With the answer of @phg, I use this function for Julia:

```
function leaky_relu(features, alpha)
    features = convert(TensorFlow.Tensor{Any}, features)
    alpha = convert(TensorFlow.Tensor{Any}, alpha)
    return max(alpha.*features, features)
end
```

Comment: `leaky_relu` was added in [v1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791504/1346276), it seems. Have you checked the TF version your `TensorFlow.jl` is built against?

Comment: I checked it: My TensorFlow is build with the version 1.4.0 (const cur_version = "1.4.0"
const cur_py_version = "1.4.0" in build.jl)

Comment: Moreover, if I run Pkg.update("TensorFlow") ; no packages are updated

Comment: You could adapt you solution in the style of the implementation of [`dropout`](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/blob/fc1565aefba81f9e8317af336d3711ad1e4db52d/src/ops/nn.jl#L179) and submit a pull request to the library.

Comment: Ok, I will do it soon. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `TensorFlow.jl` only copies the C++ API, not the Python one. And [`leaky_relu` is defined](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/81012dcd91770dc8113cd5beb4f854968c27e272/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L1525) only in Python. But the implementation should be easy to translate to Julia from the original:

```
def leaky_relu(features, alpha=0.2, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name, "LeakyRelu", [features, alpha]):
        features = ops.convert_to_tensor(features, name="features")
        alpha = ops.convert_to_tensor(alpha, name="alpha")
        return math_ops.maximum(alpha * features, features)
```

(I don't have either library installed, so I can't test anything.)

Comment: I edited my question with the function for Julia. Thank you

Comment: It would be totally appropriate here to give that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Could you maybe try `Tensorflow.py_tf[:nn][:leaky_relu]`? There [seems to by](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/blob/af2b58cdb570869d65c0c624815ec27aecbbdd51/src/py.jl) a builtin pycall setup...

Comment: When I try this command, there is the following error:               `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Base.RefValue{PyCall.PyObject}, ::Symbol) `     Maybe a package must be used ?